# Timeout when running specs in a project with custom decorator

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, decorator

The application runs without issues, but the test execution fails when trying to run the tests of the AppModule:

```
30 11 2016 07:56:42.254:WARN [Firefox 45.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 60000 ms. Firefox 45.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
```

Disconnected, because no message in 60000 ms.

Can't easily provide a plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

which shouldn't have been there.